# How can I do a belongsTo() relation in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, relational-database

Here is my model `User.php`

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'cell_phone', 'province_id', 'city_id', 'job'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function city()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('City');
    }
}
```

And here is a part of my controller:

```
$user_info = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
dd($user_info->city);
```

And it throws this:

> "Undefined class constant 'city'"

How can I fix the problem?

---

Tables structure:

```
// users
+----+--------+---------+----------
| id |  name  | city_id | ...
+----+--------+---------+----------
| 1  | Jack   | 5       | ...

// city
+----+--------+
| id |  name  |
+----+--------+
| 1  | Tehran |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass full class name:

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\City');
```

Or:

```
return $this->belongsTo(City::class);
```

Also, you don't need to do that:

```
$user_info = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
```

Because `Auth::user()` already has user instance loaded, you can just get city instance with:

```
Auth::user()->city
```

Comment: WTF ...! I never understand what laravel does exactly in the background.

Comment: One question, what should I do if the column names weren't standard? For example how should `$this->belongsTo(City::class);` look like if I replace the name of column `city_id ` with `city_idd` ?

Comment: @stack if name of the column is `city_idd`, change the relationship to `$this->belongsTo(City::class, 'city_idd');`

Answer (score 0):

Basically , you don't provide full path of your class name of city that's why you belongs To relation not working properly.

for example your code must be

```
return $this->belongs To('App/City');
```

Because your in app folder you have city class module and others.